# Could XV-11 break or discharge? [closed]

Tags: ros, xv-11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I use a neato xv-11 to do a scan. Until a few days ago I had no problem, now sometimes does not work because it shows very few points and a red circle appears in the center. What do you think it might be? It is powered by USB. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228583/could-xv-11-break-or-discharge?-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem increases the motor voltage that was lowered. Now it works well!

---

Originally posted by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) with karma: 94 on 2016-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-09**:
Please accept your own answer using the checkbox at left instead of changing the title to closed.

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-10**:
Ok! Thank you!